# Pygraphviz-error: AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, pygraphviz

I am now trying to visualize a graph which I created in Python. However, once I apply pygraphviz, I get an error:

```
 A=pygraphviz.AGraph(name=N.name,strict=strict,directed=directed)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 177, in __init__
    self.handle=gv.agraphnew(name.encode(self.encoding),
AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Where is my mistake?

Here is the corresponding part of the code:

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools
from itertools import combinations
from networkx import *
import pygraphviz as pgv

def blocks(n):
    nodes = com[n]
    edges = combinations(nodes, 2)
    g = nx.Graph()
    g.add_nodes_from(nodes)
    g.add_edges_from(edges)
    return g

s=blocks(0)
A=to_agraph(s)  
A.layout()
A.draw("network.ps")
```

However, while testing this I checked whether any of the other graphs can be drawn at all with pygraphviz. And they can. By simply typing this:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx import *
import pygraphviz as pgv

G=nx.complete_graph(5)
A=to_agraph(s)  
A.layout()
A.draw("network.ps")
```

I obtained a drawing of complete graph. 
What can I do in order to get this work? Thank you very muxch in advance!

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but what is `com` defined as?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this at all; the error implies that `s.name` is set to another graph, but your code creates a fresh `nx.Graph()` object so it's `.name` defaults to the empty string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, this is just a part of the code, since it is a bit too long and in order to execute it I need to open addition files files... com is defined as a list of string from which I need to obtain a (complete) graph, so that com=['fmre', 'vrweh', 'frwz', 'cnreowg', 'vngwri', 'vnfaweo',...]. Using nx.complete_graph(n) with string n is forbidden, so I need to use combinatorics...

Comment: The problem here is that `.name` has been assigned to somewhere, and your code does not do that; it doesn't really matter what `com` is set to.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters:thank you very much!